# KendoUI Bar chart not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, telerik, kendo-ui, telerik-charting

I have a page with 3 charts from kendo ui, and only one its not loading in IE8, the chart that im having problem is the bar chart with this configuration:

```
$(elementName).kendoChart({
    seriesDefaults: {
        type: "column",
        stack: stacked,
        opacity: 1.0
    },
    legend: {
        visible: true,
        position: "bottom"
    },
    series: dataSeries,
    categoryAxis: {
        categories: [CARREGADO,TENTATIVAS,ATENDIDO,CPC,BOLETOS ENVIADOS,BOLETOS PAGOS],
        labels: {
            visible: true,
            font: ".85em, Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif",
            rotation: 0
        }
    },
    valueAxis: {
        visible: true,
        max: 1,
        min: 0,
        labels: {
            visible: true
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        visible: true,
        template: "#= series.name #: #: (value * 100).toFixed (2) + '%' #"
    },
    chartArea: {
        background: "transparent"
    }
});
```

NOTE: This is a method so all the configurarion came from parameters, i tried to put the valus but if i've forgotten something important, please ask on the comments that ill update the question.

**Exception:**

> Unhandled exception at line 26, column 30453 in ../js/kendo.all.min.js
>
> 0x80070057 - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid argument.

Comment: Hm... not sure. Seems about right to me.
Any idea, folks ?

Comment: The problem in not traceable the kendo UI code seems alright it might be some other issues . Your series data or some other js code . Can you create a JsFiddle for the same .

Comment: Here you go @kaushikgandhi: http://jsfiddle.net/HdsjU/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WoW !
It took me a while to figure it out and debug it, but the problem is actually quite simple.

```
categoryAxis: {
    categories: [CARREGADO,TENTATIVAS,ATENDIDO,CPC,BOLETOS ENVIADOS,BOLETOS PAGOS],
    labels: {
        visible: true,
        font: ".85em, Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif",
        rotation: 0
    }
```

Just remove the comma right after ".85em" and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I was fighting with Kendo UI and IE8 for the last few hours. I made it to the same point as Raphael, and a few minutes ago finally I found a real cause of the "Invalid argument" exception. On IE8 you can't give just label's font size, you **have** to give a font name too. I was also having a problem with the unit ("em"), when I used px and a font name then suddenly all Kendo UI charts started to work like a charm.